# Why xUnit test case runs successfully while debugging but not while running in .NET6 and RavenDB 5.3?

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, ravendb, .net-6.0, ravendb5

The **issue** is that the below test method **works** perfectly fine while **debugging** the code but **does not work while running** it.

Below **test method** determines whether the fetch of records is successful or not.

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Fetch list of Refund Batch by Status")]
public async Task Can_Query_RefundBatch_By_Status()
{
    Store.ExecuteIndex(new RefundBatchByStatus());

    SetUpRefundBatches();

    var refundBatches = await Repo.FindAllByStatusAsync(BatchStatus.New);
   
    refundBatches.Count.ShouldBe(2);
    refundBatches[0].RefundRequests.Count.ShouldBe(5);
    refundBatches[1].RefundRequests.Count.ShouldBe(5);
}
```

Below is the **SetUpRefundBatches()** method

```
private void SetUpRefundBatches() {
    var session = Store.OpenSession();

    foreach (var refundBatch in Factory.RefundBatch.CreateRefundBatchesData())
    {
        session.Store(refundBatch);
    }

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Below is the **FindAllByStatusAsync** method

```
public async Task<List<RefundBatch>> FindAllByStatusAsync(params BatchStatus[] status)
{
    using var session = Store.OpenAsyncSession();

    return await session
        .Query<RefundBatch, RefundBatchByStatus>()
        .ToAsyncDocumentQuery()
        .WhereIn(d => d.Status, status, exact: true)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Below is the **RefundBatchByStatus** index class.

```
public class RefundBatchByStatus : AbstractIndexCreationTask<RefundBatch>
{
  public RefundBatchByStatus()
  {
    Map = docs => from doc in docs select new { doc.Status };
    Indexes.Add(x => x.Status, FieldIndexing.Exact);
  }
}
```

Please let me know if more stuff is required from my end to support this question.